# Legend Item pattern rotation or mirroring problem

Tags: highcharts

1. This is a follow-up to a previous question that was answered. You'll notice that the wind pattern in the legend is rotated. Does it makes sense to use a css override to try and fix this? Is there a trade-off with overriding?
2. Also, if I can't use reverseChart on the yAxis without messing up keyboard navigation. Is there another way to reverse this chart so that the legend lines up with what you see visually in the chart above?

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: ['#E56D0B', '#552450', '#8A6889', '#00558B', '#00a2c5', '#004b45', '#6Ba333']
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    scrollablePlotArea: {
      minWidth: 800,
      scrollPositionX: 0
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'some title'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'some subtitle'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ["2005", "2013", "2017", "2027"]
  },
  yAxis: {
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: "Carbon Emission Reduction"
    }
  },
  accessibility: {
    enabled: true,
    keyboardNavigation: {
      order: ['series', 'legend', 'chartMenu']
    },
    screenReaderSection: {
      beforeChartFormat: '<h3>{chartTitle}</h3><div>{typeDescription}</div><div>{chartSubtitle}</div><div>{chartLongdesc}</div><div>{playAsSoundButton}</div><div>{viewTableButton}</div><div>{xAxisDescription}</div><div>{yAxisDescription}</div><div>{annotationsTitle}{annotationsList}</div>'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    squareSymbol: true,
    symbolHeight: 20,
    itemMarginBottom: 10
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '%'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function() {
          false;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
  {
    name: "Coal",
    data: [
      56,
      46,
      37,
      19
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Natural Gas",
    data: [
      23,
      23,
      23,
      21
    ],
    color: {
      pattern: {
        path: {
          d: "M 5 5 m -4 0 a 4 4 0 1 1 8 0 a 4 4 0 1 1 -8 0",
          strokeWidth: 3
        },
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#F8CAF1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Nuclear",
    data: [
      12,
      11,
      13,
      12
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Wind",
    data: [
      3,
      15,
      21,
      38
    ],
    color: {
      pattern: {
        path: {
          d: "M 3 0 L 3 10 M 8 0 L 8 10",
          strokeWidth: 3
        },
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#B3FEF8"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Solar",
    data: [
      0,
      0,
      2,
      8
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Biomass",
    data: [
      1,
      1,
      1,
      1
    ],
    color: {
      pattern: {
        path: {
          d: "M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11",
          strokeWidth: "3"
        },
        width: "10",
        height: "10",
        opacity: "1",
        backgroundColor: "#EAFFB2"
      }
    }
  }
]
})
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#chart-container {
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Roboto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #F6F8FB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #797D83;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #F6F8FB;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #F6F8FB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/venn.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, I think that using the CSS will be the best option to fix it.
2. You can use the `legend.reversed` feature to achieve it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9mn62pcs/

```
  legend: {
    squareSymbol: true,
    symbolHeight: 20,
    itemMarginBottom: 10,
        reversed: true
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.reversed

---

Also, I found out that if you want to keep the schema from your previous question you can define the `series.index` for each series to decide about the point rendering order.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4oc9ew5x/